# How to use inout variables with closures defined by other sources?

Tags: swift, macos, foundation

I'm relatively new to Swift and was wondering how I could achieve this exact thing.

I have a Swift process, and I want to toggle a flag on completion, and I have the following code:

```
task.terminationHandler = { process in
    isTaskComplete.toggle()
}
```

I have this exact code duplicated in various views and was trying to convert it to a function, with my first attempt of referencing the `isTaskComplete` flag by using `inout`.

However, because `terminationHandler` itself defines the parameters of the closure it takes, there is no way for me to attach a secondary `inout` parameter. I was wondering if there was any way for me to reference the flag inside the closure and have the value be referenced?

For what it's worth in using Swift 5 and Xcode 11.5.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `protocols` and `protocol extensions` for that.

```
protocol NameYourProtocol {
    var task: TypeOfTask { get } // { get set } If you need
    var isTaskComplete: Bool { get } 
}

extension NameYourProtocol {

    func handleTermination() {
        task.terminationHandler = { process in
            isTaskComplete.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what you will do in every class you need to call it:

```
class Worker: NameYourProtocol {
    // This will be required by protocol.
    var task = TypeOfTask()
    var isTaskComplete = false

    init() {
        // Call `handleTermination` where you need to.
        handleTermination()
    }
}
```